# bathroom sink drain line

Tags: plumbing, pipe

My bathroom sink drain was clogged.  Since drain stop had been out, figured something fell down hole into  p trap.   Anyway, when I went under sink, learned P Trap piece was connected to pipe with duct tape.  When tape was removed, top of pipe leading to cast iron drainpipe was corroded and crumbled in my hands.   Figured I would disconnect this pipe at base and get a new matching piece to replace it. (This pipe was about one and a half feet long with a small curved bend at top that P Trap attached to.)

Problem is I can not remove this pipe from cast iron pipe going down through floor.  Threading is on outside of cast iron, but this pipe is inserted into cast iron.  Should I attempt to cut this pipe and couple a new pipe to it? Or do I need to get plumber to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what pipe you are thinking of cutting.  and it almost sounds like you aren't vented.  Pics would be nice.  I'd avoid attempting to cut any cast iron.  You might have to get the right adapter from a plumbing supply store.

Comment: thank you. I went to a big box store, studied all the fittings, got advice from a few prople then bought a PVC S tube kit, cut the old 12 inch pipe  that connected to the cast iron and used a coupler to join the pvc to the old metal.

Comment: You should enter your solution as an answer and then accept it.